# Can't connect to MySQL server on localhost (10061) on window XP. Error connecting to mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm using mysql 5.0 and easyphp. While connecting to sql server I'm receiving the above error. When I tried to check the connection with

```
telnet localhost 3306
```

it says

> could not open connection to the host. connection failed.

What should I do now? I've already turned off my firewall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that mysql is running? Is it possible that you have skip_networking in your configuration file? See:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html

[SOURCE: http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/186288]

Comment: in windows processes i can see mysqld.exe running

Comment: Then check your mysql log-file.

Comment: @DiViSOR what should i check for in mysql log file? And i'm using easyphp. so should i check for the log file in easyphp folder (under easyphp\mysql)?

Answer (score 3):

Open `my.ini` file from `mysql/bin/`

And remove hash (`#`) from line `#bind-address="127.0.0.1"`

If that line doeasn't exist, paste `bind-address="127.0.0.1"` in `[mysqld]` part.

Restart mysql and everything should be working again.

[SOURCE: easyphp faq]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have MySql Server installed in running in your machine or get it from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=460602 
That is how i solved the same problem.

Please remember to configure to the port number corresponding to the one one you used for your database application(3306 is the common one)

The password you entered when configuring MySQL Server should be the one you use to connect to your database(and it shouldn't be NULL)